# Convert a dfa to rule for a asterisk case

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar, dfa, parser-generator

Here is a simple but very common grammar rule case in EBNF format, the `Statements` is a none terminal symbol and `Statement` is none terminal symbol:

```
Statements ::= (Statement ';')*
```

After converting this rule to NFA, and then do the subset contruction for converting the NFA to DFA, and at last get the dfa:

```
State0 -> Statement -> State1 -> ';' ->State0
State0 -> ε -> State0
```

The `State0` is the DFA's start state representing the none terminal symbol `Statements`, also it is the finish state.
From `State0` input `Statement` and traslate to `State1` and input ';' at `State1`,  translate to `State0`.
Also, `State0` could translate to self with the `ε`.

And after converting the above dfa to regular grammar following the algorithm in dragon book, i get the following grammar rules:

```
Statements -> ε
Statements -> Statement Extend_NT
Extend_NT  -> ';' Statements
```

It added the new none terminal symbol `Extend_NT`, but i want to get the following the regular grammars  which does not contain the extend symbol `Extend_NT`:

```
Statements -> ε
Statements -> Statement ';' Statements
```

So the question is that is there any algorithm could get the above result that does not contain the new none terminal symbol `Extend_NT`?

Or it is just a engineering problem?

Comment: The conversion of the grammar containing `Extend_NT` to the grammar without the non-terminal is just an [unfold](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/blob/main/doc/refactoring.md#unfold) refactoring followed by the removal of the `Extend_NT` production, which you can do because it is an unused production. The conversion from a recursive rule to one containing a kleene operator is another refactoring. There is no goal-based algorithm that automatically converts one grammar to another.

Comment: @ kaby76 yes, you are right. It is a enginerring a problem. I have solved this by removing the extend symbol in parsing stage. For example, in LALR parsing stage, when to reduce a symbol, i can remove the extend symbol at same time and append the extend symbol's childs to its parent symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your question.

If you just have a single production for a non-terminal and that production just has a single repetition operator, either at the beginning or the end, you can apply a simple desugaring: (Here `α` and `β` are sequences of grammar symbols (but not EBNF symbols), and `α` might be empty.)

```
N ::= α (β)* ⇒  N → α | N β
N ::= (β)* α ⇒  N → α | β N
```

If `α` is empty, you could use either of the above. For an LALR(1) parser generator, the left-recursive version would be the usual choice; if you're building an LL parser, you will of course want the right-recursive version.

If there is more than one EBNF operator in the right-hand side, then you will need extra non-terminals, one for each EBNF repetition operator, except possibly one.

I don't know whether you'd call that an algorithm. I personally think of it as engineering, but the difference is not absolute.

Comment: you are right. It is a enginerring a problem.Maybe  i should make the grammar left-recursive, because i used a LALR(1) parser generator.